# soap parsing in ios get json response , my first step

Tags: ios, web-services, soap

i am new in soap parsing , my client give me webservices url and tail me this is .net webservices soap parsing and get json return , so i don't know where should i start , most of time i am using php webservices but this is new for me , and i try to last 4 days , i have download lots of example but i can't able go get response and before this question 5 days ago i post one question but i cant get any response 
here is my webservices 
http://orderme.solyn.in/AppUserService.asmx?op=Insert

This is my question Link Please help me ,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503243/soap-parsing-in-ios-but-is-return-a-error

Comment: what is the json response

Comment: (string Result Success, string AccessToken, int AppUserId)  OR  (Errormessage)
This is reponse